# How to compare string from file to input string? (Android)

Tags: android, string, compare, text-files

Problem is that I don't know how to build these to together(code example).I'm new at Android programming and can't figure out, how to **read from text file** and **compare to** input **string**. Now I'm so far at this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBtn);
    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView);

    parbaudesPoga.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View V) {
            String check = input.getText().toString();
            if (check.contentEquals("word")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "True",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                        "False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(this.getResources()
            .openRawResource(R.raw.words));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(is);
    StringBuilder finalText = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            finalText.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bBtn);
    display.setText(finalText.toString());
```

}
}

Comment: do you want to compare a line at a time to the string or the complete file?

Answer (score 0):

Well, call a method to compare in the click listener, after you have set "check". You can make "check" an instance variable or pass it as a parameter to the method.

You can read the file in the method, and compare as soon as you have the text string, or read it at some other point before and store the text string in an instance variable.